# How can i optimise my code and make it readable?

Tags: python-3.x

The task is:
User enters a number, you take 1 number from the left, one from the right and sum it. Then you take the rest of this number and sum every digit in it. then you get two answers. You have to sort them from biggest to lowest and make them into a one solid number. I solved it, but i don't like how it looks like. i mean the task is pretty simple but my code looks like trash. Maybe i should use some more built-in functions and libraries. If so, could you please advise me some? Thank you

```py
a = int(input())
b = [int(i) for i in str(a)]
closesum = 0
d = []
e = ""
farsum = b[0] + b[-1]
print(farsum)
b.pop(0)
b.pop(-1)
print(b)
for i in b:
    closesum += i
print(closesum)
d.append(int(closesum))
d.append(int(farsum))
print(d)
for i in sorted(d, reverse = True):
    e += str(i)
print(int(e))
input()
```

Comment: It looks too complicated and irrational. Something tells me that i could use much less lines of code if i combine some functions  and cycles so they don't take so much space. Also there are some other questionable places such as double pop function. Why i can't write e.pop(0, -1)? What can i do to save up some space? As a beginner i just can't understand what i should really do: combine functions, cycles etc to make it less complicated, or leave it like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`

```
from functools import reduce

a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, a))
# 45
```

and you can just pass in a shortened list instead of poping elements: `b[1:-1]`

The first two lines:

```
str_input = input() # input will always read strings
num_list = [int(i) for i in str_input]
```

the `for` loop at the end is useless and there is no need to sort **only** 2 elements. You can just use a simple `if..else` condition to print what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop to sum a slice of a list. You can also use `join` to concatenate a list of strings without looping. This implementation converts to string before sorting (the result would be the same). You could convert to string after sorting using `map(str,...)`

```
farsum = b[0] + b[-1]
closesum = sum(b[1:-2])
"".join(sorted((str(farsum),str(closesum)),reverse=True))
```